# What is the best 1-1 chat model ? (AJAX/CI/JQ)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am creating a system in which I am planning to let User A generate a special chat link so he/she can communicate with User B. This is a 1-1 chat model. The schema of my model is below. I need to know if its practical or if it can be improved.

```
table messages
chatid; {fk}
message_id; {pk}
timestamp;
sender;

table chat
chatid; {pk}
userA;
userB;
timestamp;
```

Here is the control flow of the scenario:

1. User A has intentions to chat with User B.
2. User A goes into the generate chat session page.
3. User A selects the User B from the list.
4. User A generates the chat session /app/chatid/007
5. User A copies and pastes the URL to sent it to User B via the inbox.
6. User A and User B agree on a time they wish to chat

I know, a bit weird, because I dont know how to implement a system where user is checked for online/offline, although you could pop in if you have ideas.

1. User A opens the chat URL on hh;mm and so does User B.
2. They start chatting.
3. The page doesn't reload and they chat with fun.

The end.
Waiting for your responses.

**Editted by Asker**

I was looking at this schema. I don't know how I would further add to it to show user a/user b being online/offline; perhaps last_activity? You tell.

```
tbl_chat
-------------
chat_id (pk)
user_id_a (fk)
user_id_b (fk)
timestamp
tinyint;

tbl_msg
-------------
message_id (pk)
chat_id (fk)
user_id_sender (fk)
message_body
timestamp
```

added  tinyint; to tbl_chat
so when user A clicks kill chat, it makes it 1 , default of tinyint =0;
So that kills chat.

Comment: @joidegn Haha, what do you mean Sir.

Comment: use php long polling or node.js socket.io to do the chat: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333664/simple-long-polling-example-code

Comment: I want to make it simple not that complex as polling or node.js. And you didn't answer my question. I was talking about the model.

Comment: copying and pasting session links to each other - via an inbox.

Comment: Hehe @joidegn: as I said a basic one. You havent answered my main question yet. regarding the model.

Comment: I would offload the online/offline checks into javascript. But you should checkout longpolling and socket.io...

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of being able to extend the chat to more than two users and not having to check both chat.userA and chat.userB in your queries I would not use userA and userB in the chat table. Rather I would add a table (e.g. chat_users) which has usernames/ids (whatever you put in userA and userB) and a chatid. Apart from that I would say that messages need a body.

```
table messages
chatid; {fk}
message_id; {pk}
timestamp;
userid; {fk}
body;

table chat
chatid; {pk}
timestamp;

table chat_user
userid; {fk}
chatid; {fk}
```

Comment: Got it. So the final model is?

Comment: I just gave a thought on this. Not the best model I'd expect.

Comment: just add `user_online int default 0` to the chat_user table. Set to 1 when user logs in/turns on chat and query that for listings/profiles and to initiate chat.

Comment: @stormdrain: where? see my original question, below **editted by asker**

Comment: @AliGajani to the `chat_user` table; see my comment 2 above this one. If you want help with code, show the code you already have.